# Medium-editor get ceart position

Tags: javascript, jquery, medium-editor

I have a project use medium editor and I try to get position of caret

but I keep getting undefine. anyone know how to achieve this?

```
<textarea class='editable'></textarea>

$('.editable').keyup(function(){
        console.log(
            $(this).prev('div').selectionStart
            //$(this)[0].selectionStart //textarea
        )
    });
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I was able to get the selection thanks to one of the extensions.

Answer (score 1):

There are some static helper methods for dealing with selections exposed via `MediumEditor.selection`.  I think the method you'd be looking for is the `getSelectionStart()` method which would return the element where the selection starts (or the element the cursor is next to if the selection is empty).  This helper takes a single argument, a reference to the document. Example:

```
MediumEditor.selection.getSelectionStart(document);
```

Also, if you're trying to monitor keyup for the editor, you can subscribe to all keyup events for any elements monitored by the editor by calling this:

```
var editor = new MediumEditor( ... );
editor.subscribe('editableKeyup', listener); // listener would be your custom event handler function
```

MediumEditor exposes a bunch of helper events and some custom events for you.  You can find documentation for the `editableKeyup` event as well as the full list of custom events [here](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/CUSTOM-EVENTS.md)